# How we change boolean state in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a state named isFocused and it is false. When I focus on my input, I want it to turn true. I tried so many things but couldn't handle it. These are what I did.

**Initial State**

```
export default {
    isFocused: false
}
```

**Action Type**

```
export const SEARCH_ACTION = "SEARCH_ACTION"
```

**Action**

```
export function searchAction() {
    return { type: actionTypes.SEARCH_ACTION, payload: null }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
export default function navbarReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.SEARCH_ACTION:
            
            return {
                ...state,
                isFocused: !state.isFocused
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**UI**

```
focusHandler() {
   console.log(this.props.isFocused)
}

<input
  placeholder="Search in Facebook"
  onFocus={() => this.focusHandler()}
/>

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        isFocused: state.NavbarReducer
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NavSec1)
```

It shows always false in console. How can i solve this ? I am new in redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` is to read the value from the store and make it accessible in your component.

To change the state in your store you need to dispatch an action, the `connect` in react-redux takes a second argument called as `mapDispatchToProps` .

```
import searchAction from 'your action file path';

focusHandler() {
  // dispatch the action 
  this.props.searchAction();
}

<input
 placeholder="Search in Facebook"
 onFocus={() => this.focusHandler()}
/>

function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
       isFocused: state.NavbarReducer
   }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {searchAction})(NavSec1)
```

Now onInputFocus you will dispatch an action to the store which toggle's the isFocused state in your store. To check this, You can do

```
console.log(this.props.isFocused)
```

inside your `render` method above your `return` you should be seeing the state getting changed onFocus.